"file not included in module tree" diagnostic for file included using include! macro
I have a simple project in rust with:
main.rs:
mod x { include!("x.rs"); }

fn main() {
    x::x();
}

and x.rs:
pub fn x() { }

and a standard, generated Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "ma"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust- 
lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

The code compiles fine and clippy shows no lints. However, rust-analyzer shows a diagnostic for the file x.rs: "file not included in module tree". I could not find any rust-analyzer issue that would match this exact problem as an issue in rust-analyzer.
Is this correct behavior that a file included via include!() macro is "not included in module tree"?

In this specific case, just mod x; would be equivalent to your code and fix the rust-analyzer error.

I'd classify that as bug in RA, but include is so exceptional for that usecase that it hardly has any priority.

@Jmb I know, this question is about rust-analyzer's correctness specifically, and the code pasted is an MRE of a problem in a larger macro that isn't even mine and where the use of include! may or may not be justified. Thanks anyway!
